# EmailMessage object created outlook integration

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I have enabled enhanced email in the org and I am trying to write a trigger to restrict email logging against certain objects using Outlook Add-In. However, I cannot find what determines an EmailMessage object created from outlook against an EmailMessage from a regular email such as Email2Case since users should be able to log in against Case as well. I looked at the [emailMessage object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) and it does not say anything in the documentation about how the email was created.

In other words, is there a field in EmailMessage api that would help me determine the source of the email?

Answer (score 1):

These may be of some assistance:

Option 1:

`EmailMessage.CreatedById` will be the User setup in `Setup | Support Settings | Automated Case User`

In every org I have worked on, the `Automated Case User` is a headless user (i.e. not associated to a real person) and such user would be unlikely to be using the Outlook Add-In

Option 2:

`EmailMessage.ParentId` is non null when created by Email-to-Case.  `EmailMessage.RelatedToId` will be non-null for all other `EmailMessage` including Outlook Add-In. Use `EmailMessage.Incoming = true` to filter only inbound email messages

Option 3 (hypothesis, untested):

`EmailMessage.Headers` may contain text that distinguishes Outlook Add-In emails from all other `EmailMessage.Incoming = true`